# Join tables with different date fields

Tags: sql, join, netezza

I'm trying to join tables that have different date fields to chronologically align it.

My tables look like:

Table 1:

```
id     date_1        val
--------------------------
1     08/20/2018     0.4   
1     08/21/2018     0.4   
1     08/22/2018     0.5  
1     10/05/2018     0.8           
2     01/05/2019     0.1   
2     02/10/2019     0.4   
2     02/11/2019     0.3
```

Table 2:

```
id     date_2       total
---------------------------
1     08/18/2018    31.1    
1     08/19/2018    31.12    
1     08/22/2018    32.08   
1     08/23/2018    31.5            
2     03/01/2019    22.7
```

I would like to join these tables if possible, and get:

```
id     date_1        val       date_2       total
-----------------------------------------------------
1       null        null     08/18/2018     31.1
1       null        null     08/19/2018     31.12
1     08/20/2018     0.4        null        null
1     08/21/2018     0.4        null        null 
1     08/22/2018     0.5     08/22/2018     32.08
1     10/05/2018     0.8        null        null     
2     01/05/2019     0.1        null        null
2     02/10/2019     0.4        null        null
2     02/11/2019     0.3        null        null
2       null        null      03/01/2019    22.7
```

because there are very few dates overlapping, I'm not sure how to do it... I've only dealt with left joins where 'left' table contained the dates from 'right' table. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, t1.date_1,
       t1.val, t2.date_2, t2.total
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date_1 = t2.date_2
```

Answer (score 0):

@jarlh is correct, though you will have to alias the id field in one of the tables. You want

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  Table_1
FULL OUTER JOIN
   Table_2
      ON Table_1.id = Table_2.id t2id
;
```